# Send messages between iPhone & Mac

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, bonjour

I'm fairly novice in iPhone development, but trying to create what would seem a fairly simple application.

I want to have 1 program running on my phone/simulator that has a slider and a button, and another receiving program on the mac, such as Processing/Supercollider.

When the button is pressed i want a String such as "hello" to appear in the post window of the program on the mac, and when the slider is moved up/down for an integer, say between 0-99, to correspond with the movement on the phone. I'm assuming a WiFi connection would be essential for the sending of messages between devices.

Does anyone know how I might go about writing this - tutorials/code examples/links to get me started?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

[cocoaasyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) is a great wrapper around CFSocket and CFStream, that makes networking much easier. Bonjour has great documentation at [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com)

Answer (score -1):

This should be done over a TCP connection which is established between your iPhone and the PC. For that to happen you need to write 2 pieces of software:

1) A client: to be installed on your iPhone

2) A server: to be installed on your PC

The server will listen to connections coming from the iPhone and once a connection is made you can send messages quite easily between the two.

This will give you a good grasp on the theory
[Guide to socket programming in C](http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/PracticalSocketC.pdf)

Once you have that then you can find tons of Obj-C TCP examples.